# Show excerpt if no title in admin view

Tags: admin, hooks, get-posts

Usually my posts do not have a title, so in the admin view it always says "(no title)" wherever the title would be shown.

So I am wondering how I could hook into that view function. I would like to check whether the post has no title, and if so, show a custom length excerpt of lets say the first 10 words of the post instead. But only in the admin view, so that in the frontend it only shows a title if there actually is one.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following approach using the `the_title` filter in the `edit.php` screen:

```
/**
 *  Modify post titles in the edit.php screen.
 *  If the post title is empty, then show max 10 words from the post content instead.
 */
add_action( 'load-edit.php', function()
{
    add_filter( 'the_title', function( $title )
    {
        $post = get_post();
        if( is_a( $post, '\WP_Post' ) && ! $post->post_title && $post->post_content )
            $title = wp_trim_words( strip_shortcodes( strip_tags( $post->post_content ) ), 10 );
        return $title;
    } );
} );
```

where we display max 10 words from the post content if the title is empty.

Comment: Great stuff! I made this a separate function and also added it to load-index.php, so it also works on the dashboard. Thank you!

Comment: you're welcome, great to hear it worked for you @mcnesium

Comment: I just realized, that on the dashboard in the activity box, the titles for the comments are not correctly substituted. It looks like it is using the oldest of the last five contents for all of them, see http://i.imgur.com/ClQrbDX.png
Do you have an idea, why that happens?

Comment: Brilliant function. This should really be built into WP core for post types formats like aside, link, quote and status